# Dynamic meta (keywords, description)

Tags: php, html, meta

I know that that this topic has been elaborated on many times, but I can still not figure out how to do it. Maybe My site structure is not like it should; I don't know.
Anyway, I have the following:

An Index.php containing a heading in which I have :

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pg_desc; ?>"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pg_key; ?>"/>
```

This index.php is also containing all the referenced stylesheets and jquery code.

Then I have all content of the pages in SQL. Each page in my database is formatted as follows (as a longtext):

```
<?php ##commented out page name just for my own convenience ?>
<div class="#" 
body
</div>
```

Now I thought I had to put 
`$pg_desc = "my page is about"` 
and 
`$pg_key = "you,name,it"` 
in the php part, but that did not seem to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: Appearently the keywords and description arent there (according to http://www.submitexpress.com/cgi-bin/analyzer/metahtn.pl)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to declare that variables before outputting them to meta tags.

For example:

```
<?php
$pg_key = "you,name,it";
$pg_desc = "my page is about";
?>

<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pg_desc; ?>"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pg_key; ?>"/>
```

Comment: Should I then put 
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pg_desc; ?>"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pg_key; ?>"/>

in the content of all my pages?

Comment: Where are you getting the $pg_key and $pg_desc from? If they are the same in every page, you don't really need PHP, you could use just HTML for it. The propuse of this is by pulling the data for each page from database.

Comment: the Pg_key and Pg_desc are in the body part of my database, so above the text of a certain page there is: <?php $pg_key="key,for,this,particular,page ?> which is then followed by the actual content.

Comment: For that to work, you will need to put those variables statements before the meta tags, or it will don't have content to be reproduced.

Comment: Edit: still does not seem to work. I used your example and then followed by the content of my website.

Comment: What does not work? What happens? What is the error? What is supposed to happen that does not?